# Why does my project not build when I try to import it to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, string-concatenation

I have been working on a Java project in Eclipse. The project uses JDK 8 and JUnit 4, both of which are reflected in the build path. With the previous version of Eclipse I had installed, I was able to import this project, edit it, run tests, etc. without issues.

However, I recently updated my MacBook to Sonoma and also had to update Eclipse as a result. When I try to import my project into the new version of Eclipse, I receive the following error:

"The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory. Fix the build path then try building this project."

I don't think my project contains anything that requires StringConcatFactory. It does contain a class called Concat that is saved in a file called Concat.java, although I tried changing that (both the name of the class and name of the file) and it didn't help.

Does anyone have any insight as to why I might be getting this error message when the project was running fine on the prior version of Eclipse?

Comment: `StringConcatFactory` was introduced in Java 9, Eclipse is probably using Java 8 or older. Is a newer version installed? Is that project configured to use it? How is it being built?

Comment: My build path is:  

abcplayer/src
abcplayer/test
JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8]
JUnit 4
antlr.jar - abcplayer/lib

Eclipse lists my installed JREs as:
Java [1.8.391.13]
Java SE 8 [1.8.0_391]
JRE [17.0.10]

I have tried setting all these as the default but that did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Java 17 should have been fine for this. Note that the current version of Java is Java 21, newer versions of Java have lots of nice features.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I was able to get it to work by going into the build path and updating the version of Java the project uses to Version 9. Hopefully that doesn't create any other issues with the project (it doesn't look like it will, as the project is no longer throwing any errors in Eclipse).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).